How to replicate gpt-4o-mini playground results in api on image input?
The problem
I am using system prompt + user image input prompt to generate text output using gpt4o-mini. I'm getting satisfactory results when I attempt this on the chat playground UI. But the same thing, when done programmatically using python API, gives me poor results.
My suspicion is that openAI uses some kind of image transformation and compression on their end before inference which I'm not replicating. But I have no idea what that is. My image is 1080 x 40,000. (It's a screenshot of an entire webpage). But the playground model is very easily able to find my needles in a haystack.
My workflow
Here's my process:

Getting the screenshot

google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1024,40000
--screenshot=destination.png  source.html


convert to base64

def encode_image(image_path):
  with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
    return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')


get response

data_uri_png = f"data:image/png;base64,{base64_encoded_png}"
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o-mini",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": query},
        {"role": "user", "content": [
            {
                "type": "image_url",
                "image_url": 
                    {"url": data_uri_png 
                }
            }
        ]}
    ]
)

What I've tried

converting the picture to a jpeg and decreasing quality to 70%
chunking the image into smaller images 1080 x 4000 images and uploading multiple as input prompt

What am I missing here?
